# Phonegap notification options that work for both for iOS and Android

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am building mobile apps for iOS and Android using PhoneGap Build. I would like to send push notifications to both types of device using the same server-side process. Is this possible?

Apple's certification process to enable push notifications is painful, much more so than anything available for Android. Do I have to use it?

GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) says it supports both operating systems, but the more I read about it - with respect to Phonegap - the less I see iOS mentioned! And sadly the GCM/Phonegap plugin doesn't support *subscribing to a topic*, which is a way of sending one message out to all devices in one go via a 'global' topic.

UrbanAirship and PushWhoosh seem to integrate with Phonegap, but I am forced to use their website to create my messages. GCM looks more attractive in this respect, because I can get our own ASP.NET server to talk to GCM via HTTP and thus control messages from our databases.

**Main question: Are there any options for a single server-side option which can send push notifications to both iOS and Android via a single Phonegap plugin?** (Ideally I would control messages from my own server, where one message can go to all Android/iOS devices in one go, and avoid as many Apple certificates as possible.~)

Comment: I'm still reading...and I find that I can use GCM for iOS apps if I have an Apple certificate (APN) which might involve fiddling with SSL too. So I can have a single server-side option, and single client-side option...but I cannot escape from Apple certificate hell. Is this right?